Adjusting axe position after applying constrained_layout
Using constrained_layout, I can get this plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 200
var_xx = 1**2  # var x = std x squared
var_yy = 1**2
cov_xy = 0.5
cov = np.array([[var_xx, cov_xy], [cov_xy, var_yy]])

rng = np.random.default_rng()
pairs = rng.multivariate_normal([0, 0], cov, size=N, check_valid="raise")


mosaic = [[".", "top"], ["left", "main"]]
fig, axarr = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, constrained_layout=True, width_ratios=[0.5, 1], height_ratios=[0.5, 1])

axarr["main"].scatter(pairs[:, 0], pairs[:, 1], alpha=0.5)
axarr["top"].hist(pairs[:, 0], bins=20)
axarr["left"].hist(pairs[:, 0], bins=20, orientation="horizontal")

axarr["left"].sharey(axarr["main"])
axarr["top"].sharex(axarr["main"])

axarr["top"].tick_params(labelbottom=False)
axarr["main"].tick_params(labelleft=False)
ticklabels = axarr["top"].get_yticklabels()

axarr["main"].set_xlabel("x")
axarr["left"].set_ylabel("y")
axarr["left"].set_xlabel("PDF")
axarr["top"].set_ylabel("PDF")



The horizontal spacing between the subplots is larger than the vertical one, due to constrained layout leaving space for the tick and axis labels of the top subplot. I would like to ignore this and reduce the horizontal spacing to the same as the vertical one.
One approach I tried was to set the main axe position after, hence by adding this at the end of the code:
pos_main = axarr["main"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
pos_top = axarr["top"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
pos_left = axarr["left"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)

space = pos_top.ymin - pos_main.ymax
pos_main.update_from_data_x([pos_left.xmax + space, pos_main.xmax])
axarr["main"].set_position(pos_main.transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()))

However, this disables completely constrained_layout for this axe, hence leading to poor results.

How should I first apply constrained_layout, then disable it, and adjust the axis positions?

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#manually-turning-off-constrained-layout

Yes I read this, but I could not figure out what 'do the initial draw' meant. I tried to add plt.draw() followed by fig.set_layout_engine('none'), then followed by changing the ax position, but this just disabled constrained_layout entirely

Ok, what I needed was fig.canvas.draw() !

That's a fair point and perhaps that section could use an example.  There is an example in the legend section that uses fig.canvas.draw. [x-post]

If you look at the answer I've posted, I think it does 95% of the job. But you may see that the horizontal and vertical spacing are slightly different ... COuld you have a look at the transforms, and see where I went wrong ?

Other options:
Matplotlib v3.10 will soon be released.  You can install the pre-release version with
pip install matplotlib==3.10.0rc1

In the new release, we can tell constrained layout to ignore an axis:
axarr["top"].yaxis.set_in_layout(False)


Before v3.10, we could make the axis invisible so constrained layout ignores it and then make it visible again after turning the layout engine off.
axarr["top"].yaxis.set_visible(False)
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.set_layout_engine("none")
axarr["top"].yaxis.set_visible(True)


Following the documentation, first draw the figure using fig.canvas.draw to update all positions, and then disable the constrained layout using fig.set_layout_engine("none").
Complete solution:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 200
var_xx = 1**2  # var x = std x squared
var_yy = 1**2
cov_xy = 0.5
cov = np.array([[var_xx, cov_xy], [cov_xy, var_yy]])

rng = np.random.default_rng()
pairs = rng.multivariate_normal([0, 0], cov, size=N, check_valid="raise")


mosaic = [[".", "top"], ["left", "main"]]
fig, axarr = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, constrained_layout=True, width_ratios=[0.5, 1], height_ratios=[0.5, 1])

axarr["main"].scatter(pairs[:, 0], pairs[:, 1], alpha=0.5)
axarr["top"].hist(pairs[:, 0], bins=20)
axarr["left"].hist(pairs[:, 0], bins=20, orientation="horizontal")

axarr["left"].sharey(axarr["main"])
axarr["top"].sharex(axarr["main"])

axarr["top"].tick_params(labelbottom=False)
axarr["main"].tick_params(labelleft=False)
ticklabels = axarr["top"].get_yticklabels()

axarr["main"].set_xlabel("x")
axarr["left"].set_ylabel("y")
axarr["left"].set_xlabel("PDF")
axarr["top"].set_ylabel("PDF")

fig.canvas.draw()              # <----- draw the figure 'virtually'
fig.set_layout_engine("none")  # <----- disable constrained_layout

pos_main = axarr["main"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
pos_top = axarr["top"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)
pos_left = axarr["left"].get_position().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans)

space = pos_top.ymin - pos_main.ymax
pos_main.update_from_data_x([pos_left.xmax + space, pos_main.xmax])
axarr["main"].set_position(pos_main.transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()))
pos_top.update_from_data_x([pos_main.xmin, pos_top.xmax])
axarr["top"].set_position(pos_top.transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()))


